# Magento 2: implement your own captcha type

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1, captcha

Out of curiosity, I was going through the captcha module of M2 and I noticed this interesting code in `Magento/Captcha/Helper/Data.php`

```
public function getCaptcha($formId)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($formId, $this->_captcha)) {
        $captchaType = ucfirst($this->getConfig('type'));
         if (!$captchaType) {
             $captchaType = self::DEFAULT_CAPTCHA_TYPE;
          } elseif ($captchaType == 'Default') {
               $captchaType = $captchaType . 'Model';
          }
          $this->_captcha[$formId] = $this->_factory->create($captchaType, $formId);
    }
    return $this->_captcha[$formId];
}
```

So that code seems pretty clear to me. Magento 2 is shipped with a default captcha with the associated model being `Magento/Captcha/Model/DefaultModel`

That model implements the `Magento/Captcha/Model/CaptchaInterface` with the following methods:

```
public function generate();
public function isCorrect($word);
public function getBlockName();
```

I can see that the dev team made the code flexible enough to implement your own captcha type which is great.

So I assume that if one wants to implement its own type of captcha he will **have to create a captcha model that implements that interface.**

My question is: apart from the model creation, **what do we need to do to implement a custom captcha type** (**specially in terms of configuration**, pretty sure there's some XML going on here I was expecting a `captcha.xml` to sit somewhere but there's none)

Comment: How Can I Call captcha in product review form I am having hard time to find it. taken help with this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form but did not worked for me ! Plz help