# Magento 2: How to display captcha on Custom Form?

Tags: magento2, frontend, captcha

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0.

I have created custom form, which is not listed on **`Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> CAPTCHA`**

[image]

I would like to add my newly created custom form in to "Forms" list, so Captcha also displayed on that.

Comment: Check the link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form

Comment: You can refer **[Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form/133432)** Question definitely this will helps you. In this there is specified that how to show custom form in List.