# How to add captcha in product review form in magento2?

Tags: magento2, captcha

I am trying to add Captcha inside product review form. For that i add

```
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha" name="captcha" after="-" cacheable="false">
                <action method="setFormId">
                    <argument name="formId" xsi:type="string">user_login</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgWidth">
                    <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">230</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgHeight">
                    <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="captcha_page_head_components" template="Magento_Captcha::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
```

in `theme/Magento_Review/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file. and after that i am calling it in `/theme/Magento_review/template/form.phtml` file like

`<?php echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('form.additional.info')->toHtml(); ?>` But after that no captcha is showing in the review form. Please help me to do it. Thanks

Comment: May be you can find answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form

Comment: are there any way to implement it without creating custom module?

Comment: No magento not providing inbuilt captcha for product review form. You can see config at `stores/config/customers/customer config` in admin panel

Comment: You need to see how it works

Comment: @Yudi can you tell the solution ? I am struggling not getting clear idea how it works.

Comment: @Yudi - Have you got any solution for this? I am also struggling with this.

Comment: @AmritPalSingh I am still facing same issue.

Comment: Hi @Yudi yes i have solved this issue.

Comment: Can you please submit the solution. It would be helpful for the other developers.

Comment: @Yudi i have created a module for that. I can send the zip file as the there are many files.

Comment: sure. How can I get that?

Comment: er.amrit1 is my skype id.

Comment: Give it a try https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 1):

To use google reCaptch :
Go to Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Security Tab -> Google reCaptcha -> Frontend -> Enabled = Yes

Use in Review = select Yes

Add getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?> in your theme's Magento_Review /templates/form.phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

To add google reCaptcha in the product review form please check the following steps:

- Step 1: Go to Admin > Stores > Settings > Configuration > Security Tab > Google reCaptcha Storefront
- Step 2: Fill out the section of reCAPTCHA type(s) as per your requirement, you can check about this in detail from https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html
- Step 3: From **Storefront** section, uncheck the **Use system value** checkbox for **Enable for Product Review** location field and set it to the reCAPTCHA type that you have configured in the last step.
- Step 4: After Completion, Save Config and Check.
- Magento 2 have added **'recaptcha'** block in **'product.review.form.fields.before'** container of product review form's block and it's called from \vendor\magento\module-review\view\frontend\templates\form.phtml file as '**getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>**'