# Magento 2: How Captcha Module works?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, captcha

I am struggling with adding captcha in few forms, have gone through its module I find it really intresting but not getting clear idea ! If anyone is having clear concept please describe . 
thanks!

Comment: What u want to achieve?

Comment: I want to learn its flow, as if now I want to display a captcha on a product review form followed http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form/133432?noredirect=1#comment211843_133432 but not helped.

Comment: Which version have you tried?

Comment: @Sohel Rana magento 2.1

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147597/how-to-add-captcha-in-product-review-form-in-magento2?rq=1

Comment: Captcha module used for display captcha in magento front and backend, e.g. Register page, login page

Comment: How can I get a Captcha in my custum template file.??

Comment: Try extension https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html

Comment: @supriyamishra, is it working for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's long answer though.

> Step 1. Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <customer>
            <captcha>
                <shown_to_logged_in_user>
                    <product_review_form>1</product_review_form>
                </shown_to_logged_in_user>
                <always_for>
                    <product_review_form>1</product_review_form>
                </always_for>
            </captcha>
        </customer>
        <captcha translate="label">
            <frontend>
                <areas>
                    <product_review_form>
                        <label>Product Review Form</label>
                    </product_review_form>
                </areas>
            </frontend>
        </captcha>
    </default>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Goto 'Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Customer -> Customer
>   Configuration -> Captcha' and configure. You can able to see new forms
>   value 'Product Review Form'
>
> Step 3: Create
>   Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::review/form.phtml</argument>
                </action>
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info">
                    <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha" name="captcha" after="-" cacheable="false">
                        <action method="setFormId">
                            <argument name="formId" xsi:type="string">product_review_form</argument>
                        </action>
                        <action method="setImgWidth">
                            <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">230</argument>
                        </action>
                        <action method="setImgHeight">
                            <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
                        </action>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="head.components">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="captcha_page_head_components" template="Magento_Captcha::js/components.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

> Step 4: Vendor/Moduel/view/frontend/templates/review/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Review\Block\Form
 */
?>
<div class="block review-add">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Write Your Own Review') ?></strong></div>
<div class="block-content">
<?php if ($block->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()): ?>
<form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAction() ?>" class="review-form" method="post" id="review-form" data-role="product-review-form" data-bind="scope: 'review-form'">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset review-fieldset" data-hasrequired="<?php __('* Required Fields'); ?>">
        <legend class="legend review-legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("You're reviewing:"); ?></span><strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?></strong></legend><br />
        <?php if ($block->getRatings() &amp;&amp; $block->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
        <span id="input-message-box"></span>
        <fieldset class="field required review-field-ratings">
            <legend class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Your Rating') ?><span></legend><br/>
            <div class="control">
                <div class="nested" id="product-review-table">
                    <?php foreach ($block->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                        <div class="field choice review-field-rating">
                            <label class="label" id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control review-control-vote">
                            <?php $options = $_rating->getOptions();?>
                            <?php $iterator = 1; foreach ($options as $_option): ?>
                                <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="ratings[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_rating->getId() ?>]"
                                    id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>"
                                    value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getId() ?>"
                                    class="radio"
                                    data-validate="{required:true, messages:{required:'Please select one of each of the ratings above.'}}"
                                    aria-labelledby="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>_label" />
                                <label
                                    class="rating-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $iterator; ?>"
                                    for="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>"
                                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star') ?>"
                                    id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>_label">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star') ?></span>
                                </label>
                            <?php $iterator++; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?php endif ?>
        <div class="field review-field-nickname required">
            <label for="nickname_field" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Nickname') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: nickname()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-summary required">
            <label for="summary_field" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Summary') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().title" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-text required">
            <label for="review_field" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Review') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().detail"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar review-form-actions">
        <div class="primary actions-primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit Review') ?></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#review-form": {
        "Magento_Review/js/error-placement": {}
    }
}
</script>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info notlogged" id="review-form">
        <div>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%1">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginLink(), $block->getRegisterUrl()) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
</div>
```

> Step 5: Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_review_product_post">
        <observer name="captcha_product_review_form" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckProductReviewFormObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 6: Vendor/Module/Observer/CheckProductReviewFormObserver.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Captcha\Observer\CaptchaStringResolver;

class CheckProductReviewFormObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_helper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;

    /**
     * @var CaptchaStringResolver
     */
    protected $captchaStringResolver;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     * @param CaptchaStringResolver $captchaStringResolver
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        CaptchaStringResolver $captchaStringResolver
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->captchaStringResolver = $captchaStringResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Check CAPTCHA on review Form
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $formId = 'product_review_form';
        $captcha = $this->_helper->getCaptcha($formId);
        if ($captcha->isRequired()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

            if (!$captcha->isCorrect($this->captchaStringResolver->resolve($controller->getRequest(), $formId))) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $this->getDataPersistor()->set($formId, $controller->getRequest()->getPostValue());
                $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), $this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Data Persistor
     *
     * @return DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private function getDataPersistor()
    {
        if ($this->dataPersistor === null) {
            $this->dataPersistor = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(DataPersistorInterface::class);
        }

        return $this->dataPersistor;
    }
}
```

Clear magento cache.

Comment: complete review form is blank means there is no form now!!

Comment: You follow every step?

Comment: yes Completely !!

Comment: Do I need to change anything in my custom theme ??

Comment: Could you replace 'Vendor_Module' to 'YourVendor_YourModule' from catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: Check <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::review/form.phtml</argument> line and don't forget to clear cache

Comment: Yes I did !! everywhere  Still will cross check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51650/discussion-between-supriya-mishra-and-sohel-rana).

Comment: Works for me! Thanks. Using Magento 2.1.3. Make sure to change "Vendor/Module"-names and don't forget the single "<?php" before your Observer code. Don't add closing tag.