# Custom Captcha not working in Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, captcha, product-review

I want to show captcha in Product Review Form, Followed the below link.

[Magento 2: How Captcha Module works?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154376/magento-2-how-captcha-module-works)

Created the module with relevant files and I am able to see the captcha in review form.

Here everything is fine but after submit always I am getting **"Incorrect CAPTCHA"** error.

Can anyone check it and help me why the accepted answer is not working here?

My Magento version is 2.3.0.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.3 comes bundled with `msp/recaptcha` which has the option to enable recaptcha on the review form.

Possiby what you've added is conflicting

[image: ReCaptcha config]

Remove what you've added.  If you don't see the options try

```
composer require msp/recaptcha
```

Or perhaps

```
composer update msp/recaptcha
```

If that still doesn't work it could be a theme issue. If you still have problems configure Luma theme and see if you still get the same error.  If you don't get the error with Luma you will have to contact whoever developed your theme.

Comment: yes I can see recaptcha option in  admin, but there is no heading to enable for review.