# How can I delete all pending review on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, database, review

On My Magento 2 Site guest review was enabled, Someone spam review around several hundred thousand, I need to delete all pending reviews from the database. I am not interested to truncate reviews because there some real reviews approved. Also, delete from admin a few day's tasks.

I got below table:

```
email_review
review
review_detail
review_entity
review_entity_summary
review_status
review_store

rating 
rating_entity
rating_option
rating_option_vote
rating_option_vote_aggregated
rating_store
rating_title
```

Any suggestion DELETE FROM review; as relation table data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below two-step you need to follow to remove spam reviews and it will also help to add spam reviews in the frontend.

1. Remove those spam reviews from the backend or from the database manually. (you can use where condition with review_id and remove it from the database)
2. Add a captcha in the review form where it will stop allow spam reviews. This extension will help you.
   [How to add captcha in product review form in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147597/how-to-add-captcha-in-product-review-form-in-magento2)

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I already protected spam review , now i need to remove junk review

Comment: ok @matinict, for that you need to remove those from a database or Magento Backend.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Marketing > User Content > Pending Review

select All and select action as delete ( make sure pagination set to higher no )

Unless you cant manage it from the Website then only rush toward the database

Happy Coding

Comment: when select & delete website going down

Comment: Well then try 10 to 20 at once