# how to add custom captcha in custom module in frontend magento 1.9?

Tags: magento2, captcha

> Actually I am trying to add captcha in custom module in frontend
>   magento 1.9
>
> Below code is not useful.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<contacts_index_index>
    <reference name="contactForm">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymodule/contacts/form.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>contacts</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Comment: Follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133432/55928

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your config.xml file? Would be useful to take a look at the files.

Comment: I added this repo with the code I am working on: https://github.com/blovable/captcha