# How to get captcha in phtml file when phtml file directly called in controller file in magento2?

Tags: magento2, captcha

I want to add captcha in test.phtml file and test.phtml file called from controller like below:

```
 public function execute()
{      

    $response = array();
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
      $this->_coreSession->start();
      $this->_coreSession->setProductsData($post);
      $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    try {

      $block = $this->resultPageFactory->create()->getLayout()
            ->createBlock("Vendor\Modulename\Block\Popupdata")
             ->setTemplate("Vendor_Modulename::view/test.phtml")
            ->toHtml();

        /** @var array $response */
        $response = [
            'content' => $block,
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $resultJson->setStatusHeader(
            \Zend\Http\Response::STATUS_CODE_400,
            \Zend\Http\AbstractMessage::VERSION_11,
            'Bad Request'
        );
        /** @var array $response */
        $response = [
            'message' => __('An error occurred')
        ];
        $this->_logger->critical($exception);
    }

    return $resultJson->setData($response);
}
```

Comment: Please check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add below code in phtml :

```
    <?php
                $blockPath = 'Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha';
                $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($blockPath);
                $cap_data = array('form_id'=>'product-contact-cap','img_width'=>'50');
                $block->setData($cap_data);
                echo $block->toHtml();
            ?>
```

Comment: Hello Its not working