# Magento 2: How to add reCAPTCHA to Customer Address Form

Tags: magento2, customer-address, recaptcha, google-recaptcha

How can I add reCAPTCHA to Customer Account Address Edit and New address form

Comment: You can implement this by following the steps of an answer (choose between the one for 2.3 or 2.4) of [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/133238/70510)

Comment: Why do you want to add a recaptcha in My Account page? This page can be accessed by logging in.