# Child block is not loaded when the main block is called in a CMS page

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, magento2.4, custom-block

I made a custom module block with the following layout:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Form Partner</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Myvendorname\Mymodulename\Block\CaptchaForm" name="contactForm" template="Myvendorname_Mymodulename::captchaform.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info">
                    <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha" name="captcha" after="-" cacheable="false">
                        <action method="setFormId">
                            <argument name="formId" xsi:type="string">custom_form</argument>
                        </action>
                        <action method="setImgWidth">
                            <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">230</argument>
                        </action>
                        <action method="setImgHeight">
                            <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
                        </action>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="captcha_page_head_components" template="Magento_Captcha::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the template file, at a point, I have:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('captcha'); ?>
```

When I visit the module route on my browser the captcha block is shown but when call the block in a CMS page with this code

```
{{block class="Myvendorname\Mymodulename\Block\CaptchaForm" template="Myvendorname_Mymodulename::captchaform.phtml"}}
```

then I see all the main block elements but not the child block... It is not loaded.

I already tried various combinations, e.g. called the container form.additional.info with getChildHtml but it always work only visiting directly the module and it fails when I call the block in a CMS page.

Comment: Please check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form

Comment: @Msquare the topic you linked is exactly the one I followed to add the captcha to the form, but unfortunately I see the captcha only if I directly visit the module route. When I add it to a CMS static page I get the form but not the captcha.