Magento 2 : how to show google recaptcha at checkout login step
In my magento 2, i have 3 step checkout [login at checkout, billing step, payment step]
when i enabled default magento 2 google recpatcha setting for checkout, am able to see captch at payment step, its not coming in the fist two steps.
how i can achive this to show on all three steps??
thanks.

If you are using the latest version Magento 2.4.5, then this is the default feature to enable the Recaptcha at the checkout process.

Please look into it to configure: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/google-recaptcha.html
Note: For enable at checkout login form,you need to enable login captcha it will also applicable on checkout as well.

Hi Gohil Rajesh, thanks your responce. if i want to show in my checkout custom step, how can i achive this?

custom step mean custom form, then you have to create separate captcha for that form

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form/340489#340489

You may need to get any third party module which allow you to add recaptcha at any custom form/page
OR
You can refer to this https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible  for implement recaptcha at any form/page via own code.
